# My app seems to generate wrong urls in html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm useing ui-router 0.3.1 and it seems as if the `otherwise('/login')` function is causing problems. When in hashbang mode it redirects me to the proper `https://localhost:7000/#/login` URL. But when in html5 mode it tries to chenge the url to `https://login`.
That behaviour is stopped by angular and seems to lead to an infinite digest cycle.

Any idea what causes this behaviour?
I'm happy to provide additional information to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you check for base tag in your root index.html file. It goes like `<base href="path_to_ui_app"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `<base href="{{BASE}}">`does not work at all, a switch to `<base href="/">`fixed the problem.